# bitcoinrpc error

Tags: json-rpc

I was happily using bitcoinrpc until I moved to python3 (python3.6.4 at the moment) and it stops working. Now I'm trying to use this one: https://github.com/XertroV/bitcoin-python3
After completing install I run the code:

> import bitcoinrpc
>
> access = bitcoinrpc.connect_to_local()
>   access.getinfo()

Getting the following error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "/home/phglz/Desktop/Satoshing/backend.py", line 8, in 
>       access.getinfo()   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/bitcoin_python3-0.3.1-py3.6.egg/bitcoinrpc/connection.py",
>   line 133, in getinfo   File
>   "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/bitcoin_python3-0.3.1-py3.6.egg/bitcoinrpc/proxy.py",
>   line 116, in **call**   File
>   "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/bitcoin_python3-0.3.1-py3.6.egg/bitcoinrpc/proxy.py",
>   line 67, in request   File "/usr/lib/python3.6/http/client.py", line
>   1239, in request
>       self._send_request(method, url, body, headers, encode_chunked)   File "/usr/lib/python3.6/http/client.py", line 1285, in _send_request
>       self.endheaders(body, encode_chunked=encode_chunked)   File "/usr/lib/python3.6/http/client.py", line 1234, in endheaders
>       self._send_output(message_body, encode_chunked=encode_chunked)   File "/usr/lib/python3.6/http/client.py", line 1026, in _send_output
>       self.send(msg)   File "/usr/lib/python3.6/http/client.py", line 964, in send
>       self.connect()   File "/usr/lib/python3.6/http/client.py", line 936, in connect
>       (self.host,self.port), self.timeout, self.source_address)   File "/usr/lib/python3.6/socket.py", line 712, in create_connection
>       sock.bind(source_address) TypeError: getsockaddrarg: AF_INET address must be tuple, not int

This issue has been posted before but not solution has been reported. I searched all over the web as much as I could.

If someone out there has an idea of what could be wrong I would appreciate his knowledge.
Thanks a lot.

Felipe

Comment: I actually asked a more generic question about Python libraries to interact with Bitcoin-Core. https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/73815/need-advice-for-python-interaction-with-bitcoin-core-wallet but haven't got any answer. If you are interested, would you please upvote to attract some attentions?

Answer (score 1):

The library did not have an update in 3 years. The `getinfo` call it attempts has been deprecated for a while and was removed with the 0.16 release of bitcoind. The solution here is to abandon the library and look for other options. Doing the rpc queries directly with python is not very hard.