# need advice for Python interaction with bitcoin-core wallet

Tags: bitcoin-core, bitcoind, python

I've read about a few Python libraries that performs JSON-RPC calls to `bitcoind`. However, not many are actively developed/maintained, nor are they widely used in production environment. Since `bitcoind` evolves over time, these hard-coded Python functions may not work well with all the different versions of `bitcoid` -- some new functions are added while others may get deprecated.

And for any general purpose JSON-RPC library, we basically need to write all the wrappers of the function calls. It shouldn't be hard, but itself is another project.

I could've just use `bitcoin-cli` and let Python do `subprocess` calls, then the problem comes with parsing those `stdout`. Most of the time, they are just JSON format, except when they are not ...

**Question: can anyone recommend the best solution for Python program to interact with `bitcoind`?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you miss how these libraries are implemented, in fact, the standard implementation of python JSON-RPC library already discover RPC function and map to python function, [here](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/API_reference_(JSON-RPC)#Python) you can read the official wiki.

If you read the code of [this library](https://github.com/jgarzik/python-bitcoinrpc) you cannot find the specific implementation for every method, it's a generic wrapper around the implementation of JSON-RPC standard library.

The feature of this wrapper in detail are specified in `README.md` file.